# Automation of Subtotal range picking

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

For my internship I am trying to do an analysis of travel patterns in public transport.
Due to privacy reasons I cannot share the file, but I may describe the columns.
This is how it works.

I have a spreadsheet in Excel (2007) and it is called ReizigersData. That contains 15,000 rows of checkins.

The columns are: stopname, stopID, problemStop, D, E, productname, workday, saturday, sunday.
stopID can be seen as a primary key.

As you'll understand, the stops are repeated in several rows, because many different productgroups travel from the same stop.

Using a Advanced filter I have filtered out 3 relevant productgroups, reducing it to approx 300 rows.

The other sheet in the file is called ReizigersData (bundled).
In this sheet I want to get the subtotals per stop, combining the numbers of the three productgroups, although separated by workday/saturday/sunday.

This sheet contains the following columns: stopname, stopID, workday, saturday, sunday.

I have used the following codes:

In ReizigersData (bundled) stopname:

=INDEX(ReizigersData!$A$3:$A$14326;MATCH(B3;ReizigersData!$B$3:$B$14326;0))

In ReizigersData (bundled) stopID:

=SUBTOTAL(109;'ReizigersData (2)'!G174:G205)

These codes work.

The problem though is that I entered that range by hand.

Since it is a big database, I would like the subtotal formula to automatically determine which range he should pick according to the stopID in the bundled sheet.

I have experimented a bit and came up with this formula:

=SUBTOTAL(109;(INDIRECT("'ReizigersData (2)'!G" & Match(B3;'ReizigersData (2)'!$B$3:$B$14326))):(INDIRECT("'ReizigersData (2)'!G" & Match(B3;'ReizigersData (2)'!$B$3:$B$14326))))

Unfortunately this does not work; it returns 0. In Formula evaluator, it looks that the reference in the match part is the issue, because it refers to row 2297, which is not the one it should be.

Has anyone got any idea how to reach my goal?

Comment: You have the same problem when you later use MATCH twice within SUBTOTAL. But beyond that, your second MATCH is identical to the first MATCH. How is that supposed to result in a different match for the last cell of the dynamic range?

Comment: @ExcelHero Okay. I already thought that, but did not know how to put in another way. I was kind of hoping that you (or others) would know...

Comment: In your initial SUBTOTAL formula, you have the range `G174:G205`. Are their any blank cells in this range?

Comment: What is the value of cell `B3` on the sheet housing these formulas?